# The function either returned None or ended without a return statement connecting python with mysql using docker

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect python with MYSQL, both are in different dockers. I can access the MYSQL from my ubuntu terminal but when I try to access with the url I used in python It doesn't work.

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
 
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - './my-vol/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/my-vol
```

Python file

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import sqlalchemy as db
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error


@app.route('/db')
def python():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="mysql", user="root", password="root", database="test")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("Select * from test_table")
        for(userId , firstName , lastName ) in cursor:
           return print("{}, {}, {}".format(userId, firstName, lastName))
```

Finally, this is the completed error that appears when I try to access /db url.

```
[2021-09-13 08:34:19,119] ERROR in app: Exception on /db [GET]
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
web_1    |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
web_1    |     return self.finalize_request(rv)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1535, in finalize_request
web_1    |     response = self.make_response(rv)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1698, in make_response
web_1    |     raise TypeError(
web_1    | TypeError: The view function for 'python' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
web_1    | 172.24.0.1 - - [13/Sep/2021 08:34:19] "GET /db HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Yes, `print(something)` always returns `None`.

Comment: Furthermore if the table is empty the execution will just "fall off" the end of the view function, which also returns `None`.

Comment: can you check if  the `host` parameter in `mysql.connector.connect()` is same as hostname of the container running the mysql database.

another thing to note is that both the containers should be on the same network, which they should be since you have created them using compose.
still as a debugging process you should be able the verify it using `docker container inspect <container_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Your view should return a response object. Instead your view returns result of the `print` function that is always `None`.

Also, your `for` loop will be exited on the first iteration due to the `return` statement. It looks like it is not what you wanted to achieve.

Your code successfully connects to mysql, otherwise you'd get a different exception.